# WebResponse and WebRequest

Tags: c#

I Have this code

// Web request section

```
private static WebRequest Web_request(string ip)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://website/");
    request.Method = "POST";
    string postData = "a=1&b=2";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    return request;        
}
```

// Web response section

```
private static string Web_response(WebRequest request)
{
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

    return responseFromServer;
}
```

and main program

```
void Main()
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < counter; ii++)
    {
        req[ii] = Web_request(ip_ext[ii]);
    }
    for (int ii = 0; ii < counter; ii++)
    {
        string domen = Web_response(req[ii]);
    }
}
```

But on the 3rd step of Web_request loop program show back the Form1 and freezes. Probably i should close something on web_request section..
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to seperate methods as request and response

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = Constants.HTTPVerbGet;
req.KeepAlive = false;
req.Accept = Constants.HTTPRequestType;
using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string objJson = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
    }
}
```

try this..

Comment: it should be faster to call all requests before the replies come back